# Variable not updating after hitting while loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the next piece of code:

```
//code...

      const charts: string[] = [];

      let thisWontUpdate = val[endOfWord];

      while (isSpecialChar(thisWontUpdate)) {
        charts.push(thisWontUpdate);
        endOfWord--;
      }

//code...
```

After being first declared the variable is not being updated after hitting the while loop yet the content does. For example:

```
//First loop
let thisWontUpdate = val[endOfWord]; //endOfWord = 4 / thisWontUpdate = 'a'

//Second loop
let thisWontUpdate = val[endOfWord]; //endOfWord = 3 / thisWontUpdate = 'a'

//Third loop
let thisWontUpdate = val[endOfWord]; //endOfWord = 2 / thisWontUpdate = 'a'
.
.
.
```

I guess you get the picture, this on the other hand does work.

```
//code...

      const charts: string[] = [];

      while (isSpecialChar(val[endOdWord])) {
        charts.push(val[endOfWord]);
        endOfWord--;
      }

//code...
```

Why is the variable not updating even after the values its being assigned are changed? thanks for the help!

Comment: `endOfWord--;` is not going to change `let thisWontUpdate = val[endOfWord];` It stores the value of there, it does not maintain it. You need to do `thisWontUpdate = val[endOfWord];` inside of the loop

Comment: because you're updating something else, not the value it was assigned.